# Excluding mocks

Tags: c++, integration-testing

If a developer would be writing integration test, to actually test full functionality of the actual code, how would one exclude mocks? Would that be in a Makefile and how would one do it?

Comment: My general setup is a main library, a production app with mainly only `main` calling the library, and a test project with tests and mock (using the library).

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you would be building a debug version (with debug symbols etc., including mocks etc.) for development / testing, and a release version (without debug symbols, excluding mocks, with optimization etc.) for integration / packaging / release.

How your build system tells your code that you are building for integration / release, and how you turn that information into the desired code structure, is up to you and your build system. Testing for `#ifdef NDEBUG` is pretty common.

Depending on your overall setup, *ideally* it would be your development-stage test code that sets up your mocks, and you wouldn't *run* those tests for integration (as that is a different kind of test altogether).

Answer (score 0):

I use polymorphism and factory pattern: mock and real class has the same interface. Factory parameter changes what concrete class (say mock of database or real database) are instantiated. This parameter resides in config file. How this parameter is changed depends on ones CI/build system. I use dedicated different test suits for mocks (unit tests) and integration, functional tests. This way the process is automated and your test framework gives you results what has been broken. Configs of each suit (unit tests or functional) set above mentioned factory parameter.